# Are there better alternatives to db triggers?

Tags: php, postgresql

I have two databases. I want to keep one table in sync. Let's call it the user table.
When one row in a table changes using a trigger I need to update the second database and the other way around.

- Is this safe?
- Is there a better way to do this?

It's not a direct PHP/PostgreSQL question, but I am using them so a specific answer might help.

Comment: Can you replace one of those tables with a view of the other? That way only one tables exists (perfectly in sync). Other answers might depend on the allowed delay between change and sync, when some seconds are acceptable you might be better off with a sync job checking every n seconds.

Comment: Triggers cannot write into tables of a different database. So you'll need to use something like Slony even if those two databases are on the same physical server.

Comment: I've done this already using dblink so it's not a big problem, I just don't like the concept.

Answer (score 1):

This works just fine going in one direction and in fact is the way the slony replication engine works.  Going in both directions not so much.  What you can do in slony is have two tables, one going in each direction, and a view on each end that the two tables into one cohesive view to the user.

Comment: Accessing a table in a different *database* from within a trigger? How does that work?

Comment: Well, if you want to go crazy, you can use dblink to do such things, HOWEVER, the way slony works is the source database puts all the data to be shoved into the destination databases into a log, which is then processed by a slon daemon.  It's no simple feat, and I'd suggest adapting the proven slony to do this rather than trying to roll your own.